# Sybase ASE 80 character limit

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

Using either `SELECT` or `PRINT` to print a string that is longer than 80 characters will cause a line wrap.

Is there a method to print lines that are longer than 80 characters?

Comment: What client tool are you using? `PRINT` itself is not limited to 80 characters, but [isql wraps at 80 by default](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility14.htm).

Comment: @Pondlife, Thanks, can you put that as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PRINT` itself does not wrap text, but isql [wraps at 80 characters by default](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility14.htm); you can change this with the `-w` switch.